# Error message for value transfer with dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, html

i created a dynamic form where you can add a form group. on a second page the input is sent by post. if i add more than one field, the radio buttons don't work anymore and the mail delivery doesn't work either

I tried to make a for-loop, but doesnt worked..

index.php (dynamic form):

```
<script>

  var ct = 1;
  function new_link()
  {
    ct++;
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = ct;
    // link to delete extended form elements
    var delLink = '<div style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px"><a href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">Delete</a></div>';
    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML + delLink;
    document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);
  }
  // function to delete the newly added set of elements
  function delIt(eleId)
  {
    d = document;
    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
    var parentEle = d.getElementById('newlink');
    parentEle.removeChild(ele);
  }
</script>

<style>
   #newlink {width:600px}
</style>
  <form method="post" action="index2.php">
    <div id="newlink">
      <div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <p>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit1">
    </p>

    <p id="addnew">
      <a href="javascript:new_link()">New</a>
    </p>
  </form>

  <div id="newlinktpl" style="display:none">
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <label>Ordner:</label>
          <td> <input type="text" name="linkurl[]" value="" placeholder="New Folder" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
         <td>
          <label>Write</label>
          <input type="radio" name="berechtigung[]  " value="W">
         </td>

         <td>
          <label>Read</label>
          <input type="radio" name="berechtigung[]  " value="R">
         </td>

         <td>
          <label>None</label>
          <input type="radio" name="berechtigung[]  " value="K  ">
         </td>
       </tr>

     </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

index2.php: (POST-DATA)

```
<?php
if(count($_POST))
{
    $len = count($_POST['linkurl']);
    for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++)
    {
        echo $_POST['linkurl'][$i] . '<br>';
        echo $_POST['berechtigung'][$i] . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: FYI: You should remove the space character after each of the `name` values in your `input` elements and `a` elements shouldn't be used just to trigger JavaScript. Any element supports a `click` event.

Comment: You are making assumptions. Need to look at possible return values / use right function for the task...`echo count("test") == true` :( See [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), [`is_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), and [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: ok. Can you help me with a code solution. I tried a lot but I'm not able to make it work :( ...

Comment: Fix the `name` as suggested. Then show us what you receive in the post... `var_dump($_POST);` Saying it "doesn't work" tells us nothing useful.